# Cocos native method for determining if a sprite is visible onscreen?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering if there is any simple tool within Cocos for automatically determining if a sprite is visible. I could code up a bunch of logic on my own, but it would be nice if Cocos already has a simple test built-in to see whether a sprite is visible or otherwise hidden behind another sprite. Since Cocos has many other tools that obviate the need for custom logic in many places, this would seem like a likely part of that toolset, but I cannot find anything so far in my searching.

It would be a simple case of having it test if the bounding box for all sprites with a higher `z` setting are covering or hiding the bounding box of the sprite in question.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with checking the `zOrder` (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a21434541d824d49ea4e84019f1445727) ... but, `zOrder` might only work if the sprites are all related somehow (if they all have the same parent.)  Found the tip from this discussion: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6252

Comment: it's a combination of z order and the sprite's bounding box in relation to sprites with a higher z order. two sprites can have different z orders but both be visible if they are in different parts of the screen.

Comment: Are you using mutiple layers or only one..

Comment: one CCLayer with multiple CCSprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to determine if two rects (the bounding boxes of the sprites) intersects:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2);
```

and then calculate the z-order.
If you want to be more precise you can calculate an index to know how much the first sprite cover the second:

```
Index = (2 * Area (CGRectIntersection(rect 1, rect2)))/(Area(rect1) + Area(rect2));
```

`CGRectIntersection` calculate the rectangle generated by the intersection of the other two.
If Index is 1 the two rectangles are precisely one above the other.